# ¿como recibir y mostrar los datos que genero de un json en un archivo php?

Tags: javascript, php

este es mi código que genera el json

```
<script>
$('#table2').on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
//  print_r(row);
         var array = {data: row};
         var paramJSON = JSON.stringify(array);
    //  print_r(JSON.stringify(array));
        console.log(array);
          $.ajax({
         data: { data: paramJSON },
         type: "POST",
         url: 'http://localhost/correo/mail.php',
         })
         .done(function( msg ) {
         console.log(msg);

         });
```

y lo quiero recibir en este archivo php y mostrar los datos pero no hace nada no se si en verdad este leyendo el archivo o le paso mal los datos, no me marca ningún error pero no muestra nada.

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST["data"]))
 {
  $data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
  var_dump($data);
  foreach($data->data as $mydata)
  {
  $idCompra = $mydata->idCompra;
  $CveSuc = $mydata->CveSuc;
  $NoOrden = $mydata->NoOrden;
  echo $idCompra." ".$CveSuc." ".$NoOrden;


  }
}
```

al hacer un print_r esto me muestra

```
data:{  
   "data":{  
      "idCompra":"1",
      "CveSuc":"ICI",
      "NoOrden":"IC001-194",
      "NomProv":"SERVICIO PARA ESTACIONES",
      "SubtPed":"2133.9741",
      "TotalPed":"2475.41",
      "StatusPart":"Surtido",
      "FalltaPed":"2016-11-01",
      "NomUser":"5",
      "statusAut":true,
      "FechHoraAut":"2016-12-13 09:40:23"
   }
}
```

lo que quiero es que con un echo muestre los datos desde el el archivo mail.php para después esos datos mandarlos por correo, lo del correo no hay problema ya que utilizo sendmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema esta en como se recibe el dato desde el `javascript` en el `php`

```
var row = [ 
    {cvesuc : '725226', noorden : '1234', idcompra : '1'}, 
    {cvesuc : '725666', noorden : '6789', idcompra : '2'}
];
var array = {data : row};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'file.php', 
    dataType: "json",
    data : {data : JSON.stringify(array)},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Si haces un `print_r(json_decode($_POST['data']))` te daras cuenta que esto llega asi :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array(
        [0] => stdClass Object(
            [cvesuc] => 725226[noorden] => 1234[idcompra] => 1
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object(
            [cvesuc] => 725666[noorden] => 6789[idcompra] => 2
        )

    )
)
```

Esto no es un objeto que te sirva para lo que quieres, por lo tanto deberias hacer es setear el parametro `assoc` del metodo `json_decode` que es basicamente

> Cuando es TRUE, los object devueltos serán convertidos a array asociativos.

```
$array_php = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
foreach($array_php['data'] as $mydata => $valor){
    echo $valor['noorden'];
}
```

**IMPORTANTE**

Tu al enviar el array haces un `JSON.stringify`, si no hace eso, ya no es necesario el `json_decode` ya que para mi ejemplo yo ARMO desde el ajax un arreglo con formato JSON, si para ti es necesario dependiendo de como armas tus datos, déjalo.

```
$array_php = $_POST['data'];
foreach($array_php['data'] as $mydata => $valor){
    echo $valor['noorden'];
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo tenias toda la razon, con esto funciono mi codigo,

Comment: $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Comment: @sonjer claro, tambien era un opcion! me alegro que te haya funcionado

Comment: pero lo hice desde aungular $scope.aprobar = function(obj) {
  $http.get(urlOrdenes + 'autorizarCompraID/' + obj.idCompra).success(function(data) {
   $scope.set_flashdata('Se autorizo la orden de compra correctamente!', 'success');
   $http({
     url : 'http://localhost/correo/mail.php',
     method : "POST",
     data : obj,
   }).success(function(data) {
    print_r(data);
   });
      $scope.loadData();
  });
 };

Comment: haaaa estabas trabajando con angular!! co0mo pusiste un ajax, asumi que estabas desde jquery

Comment: Pues como no pude por ajax, lo hice con angular y salio bien xD !!Gracias de todas formas me fue muy util tu informacion

Comment: jajaja aprovecha muy bien angularjs, pero si quieres utilizar el ajax, puedes agregar los valores de row, para poder ayudarte y ver pk fallaba el ajax

Comment: amigo al fin lo hice funcionar con tu codigo el problema era la ruta a la q yo hacia referencia y por eso no funcionaba muchas Gracias

Comment: todo estaba bien desde el principio solo era la ruta xD

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto, eso devolveria en msg de la funcion done un json:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
    // var_dump($data);

    foreach($data->data as $mydata) {

      $idCompra = $mydata->idCompra;
      $CveSuc = $mydata->CveSuc;
      $NoOrden = $mydata->NoOrden;
      echo $idCompra." ".$CveSuc." ".$NoOrden;

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

EDICION:

Ver resultados de una peticion ajax, firebug en Firefox (F12):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ver resultados de una peticion ajax, Google Chrome (F12):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sigue igual amigo no me responde ni me muestra nada, gracias comoquiera

Comment: usa la consola del navegador presiona F12 y busca la pestaña de la consola Chrome/Network o Firefox/Net alli puedes ver que exactamente devuelve tu peticion ajax